# Unity3D using WWW cannot deserialize JSON from Api response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, unity-game-engine

I am using a simple Unity application to send and receive data from my WebApi.
The Api creates models which is serialized and sent as Json.

When my Unity app receives the data it is to deserialize the Json to a similar object existing in the app.

However, the JsonUtility.FromJson is not able to deserialize the WWW.text and gives me an error.

**===API : Server Side===**

This is the model the Api will use to serialize:

```
public class MyDataContainer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the method packing and sending the response:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("get")]
public string Get()
{
    var model = new MyDataContainer()
    {
       Name = "Testsson",
       Action = _testingBackendResponseService.TestRead(),
       Age = 999
    };
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
}
```

**===Unity : Application===**
This is my client side version of the data model:

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class MyDataContainer
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Action;
        public int Age;

        public static MyDataContainer CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
        {
            return JsonUtility.FromJson<MyDataContainer>(jsonString);
        }
    }
```

This is the code triggering when I click my application's Test button:

```
    public void TestButtonClickAction()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TestGET());
    }

    private IEnumerator TestGET()
    {
        Debug.Log("Testing GET...");
        Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost:50320/TestApi/Get");
        yield return www;

        Debug.Log(www.text);
        var myjson = MyDataContainer.CreateFromJSON(www.text);
        Debug.Log("THIS IS MY DESERIALIZED OBJECT'S ACTION: " + myjson.Action);

        if (www.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(www.text);
        }
    }
```

**=== JSON strings and error message ===**

Debugging and looking at my **WWW** object i see the Text property containing the following string:

```
"\"{\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Testsson\\\",\\\"Action\\\":\\\"Ruuuun!\\\",\\\"Age\\\":999}\""
```

Looking at the printed version in my console window I see the following string:

```
"{\"Name\":\"Testsson\",\"Action\":\"Ruuuun!\",\"Age\":999}"
```

When **JsonUtility.FromJson** tries to run the www.text I get the following error:

> ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type.
>   UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson[MyDataContainer] (System.String json)
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/modules/JSONSerialize/JsonUtilityBindings.gen.cs:25)
>   ApiGetScript+MyDataContainer.CreateFromJSON (System.String jsonString)
>   (at Assets/ApiGetScript.cs:20)
>   ApiGetScript+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at
>   Assets/ApiGetScript.cs:37) UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext
>   (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

But the object does not contain a collection for which I've heard JsonUtility could have difficulties. Nor does it work when I try [this solution handling the UTF-8 encoding](https://answers.unity.com/questions/844423/wwwtext-not-reading-utf-8-text.html).

Thank you for any help I could get in this!

Comment: Your json is not valid. Why is your server sending json with bunch of "\" ?

Comment: Try `Newtonsoft` library instead of `System.Web` (which you don't want to bring into your project anyway) and see if it serializes correctly.

Comment: @Programmer That's what I thought at first too but checking serverside, it resturns a correct json string.
"{\"Name\":\"Testsson\",\"Action\":\"Ruuuun!\",\"Age\":999}"
The WWW class seem to escape the backslashes on its own accord or something.

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried switching to the Newtonsoft server side with ```return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);```
Unfortunately I get the same result in the Unity app.

Comment: *"The WWW class seem to escape the backslashes on its own accord"* Not sure. The problem is highly likely your server code and has nothing to do with Unity or `WWW` API. Try Json.NET and see if the "\" are now removed.

Comment: Are the opening and closing quotes part of the json? Coz they should not be there. Json has to start and end with { }